# AWS EMR Hive fails with execption 'java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory:' when querying S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, hive, amazon-emr

I created an external Hive table inside my aws EMR with the following script:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (
id string,
location string,
number string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '${INPUT}';
```

While ${INPUT} is my S3 Bucket in which some .csv Files are stored. The creation of the table works fine, but when I want to query the table I get the following exception:

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory: 'source/<pathtofiles>/<file>.csv'
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: store the file in a folder and point the external table to it rather than file.

Comment: @newbie the files are in a folder like "s3://bucketname/source/table/". Inside "table" there are multiple .csv files. It doesn't work if i try to point to "table" nor to "source".